# How do I fix a stuck pixel in video with libav?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libav

I have a video with stuck (hot) pixel and I'd like to fix it, let's say by replacing the pixel with average value of the neighbour pixels. I'm on Ubuntu so I'd like to use libav/ffmpeg, but don't really know how to do this. Could anyone provide a simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I came up with this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "split [main][tmp]; [tmp] boxblur=5:1, crop=W:H:X:Y [tmp2]; [main][tmp2] overlay=x=X:y=Y" -strict -2 output.mp4
```

Replace X,Y and W,H with pixel coordinates and size of the area which you want to blur. You can also change the boxblur parameters to apply more/less blur.

The solution could be improved so that the blur doesn't look at the stuck pixel, but I don't know how to do this and this seems to work.